# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Error while clicking button1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, exception

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid object name 'Login'.

Here's The Code :

```
public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Igurek\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Username='" + metroTextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + metroTextBox2.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        sdf.Fill(dt);  // <--------- Here's the exception
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Show();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sprawdz Nazwe i Haslo");
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is pretty clear: you don't have an object (table, view) in your database named `Login`.  Your query is attempting to select from that object.

```
Select Count(*) From Login where...
```

The bigger and more important issue here is that you're opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack because you're concatenating strings together to create the query.  You should use parameters instead of doing that.

```
SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "Select Count(*) From Login where Username=@UserName and Password=@Password", con);

command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = metroTextBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = metroTextBox2.Text;
```

Comment: wow thanks for making an effort . im blind and i dont know how to change the table name from "Table" to "Login" idk. brb

Comment: Thanks , i was blind or drunk (haha) when adding a question. I fixed it by deleting old Tables and making new with name "Login"

Answer (score -1):

try to set name to your count like this:

```
    Select Count(*) as Nb From Login
```